# How can you animate new added path data?

Tags: svg, css-animations

I am using SVG `<path/>` to plot x and y values. I am receiving new values and want to add them to the path with a smooth animation. How can I achieve this, or is it even possible to do such kind of things with SVG? Like this example below:
[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible, though not quite yet with pure CSS anumations.  You can't quite yet style the `d` attribute with CSS. But it's coming soon.  In the meantime, you **can** do it with [SMIL animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-animate) or with third-party JS libraries usch as Greensock's GSAP.  For more info search "SVG morphing" on here, or elsewhere.

Comment: It kind of depends on what kind of path you're drawing, but a standard animation technique is to draw the new line on top of the old one and animate its opacity from 0 to 1.